# OpenCV - Calibration target for 3D stereo camera

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

OpenCV - Calibration target for 3D stereo camera

Hi,

i try to calibrate stereo cameras with `opencv`, which i will then use to recover depth from image and estimate distances from 3D reconstructed scenes.
for this purpose, i need an asymmetric pattern, which has no 180-degree ambiguity. I found some `calibtration` target made from `aluminium/LDPE`
which offers excellent flatness and stiffness.

My question is, which target is more efficient for 3D stereo calibration?

The checkerbroard

[image]

or asymmetric cirle

[image]

target.

Would you share your experience?

Thanks!

Comment: I dont have practical experience, but in theory the circle pattern should be better if you expect some blur because of non-perfect focus. About rotation ambiguity: Maybe think about adding 4 different QR Codes in the corners (outside of the pattern) to identify orientation in close distance and big different symbols, which are well visible and distinguishable even in a big distance.

Comment: a checkerboard with "even x odd" size has the same shape as the circles grid, i.e. both are equivalently asymmetrical (have no ambiguity). your picture fits that criterion. -- circles need more thought to locate subpixel-accurately because the center of a circle, seen from a perspective, is *not equal* to the center of the ellipse that is the projection of that circle. for the chessboard, subpixel-locating those corners is easier.

Comment: feel free to think about getting advice and support from https://calib.io/ their generator might also help you to design your desired pattern.

Comment: Hey Micka, nice idea, i like it. I need to find something more information about how to implement the QR Codes. 
[Do you mean something like this example](https://temugeb.github.io/python/computer_vision/2021/06/15/QR-Code_Orientation.html)

Comment: @I2I3 for generation you can use tools like https://www.qrcode-monkey.com and you can find code online for generation of images or vector graphics. For detection I recommend zbar library, but opencv has functions, too. A detected QR code gives you positon and orientation in the image, so you can check even for 180° rotations between both camera's detected calibration patterns, if the QR codes are recognized.

Comment: a full board could look like this: https://ibb.co/NTLMwHp the inner QR code corners embed the calibration pattern (symmetric circle pattern of asymmetric size here), so that it is easier to auto-detect the presence of a QR code and its orientation. And the heart/smiley symbols allow to see the board orientaton even if the board is small in the image. I've seen such a board in practice used for both, stereo calibration and intrinsic calibration. The stereo calibration (and maybe recording test-data?) was performed in different positions in ranges of about 5-50m away from the camera.

Comment: @Micka thats means, i have to write the functions to detect the pattern myself and than i can feed the points to the cv2.calibrateCamera(...) function, korrect?

Comment: detecting the pattern itself can be done with the checkerboard or ciirclepattern functions (e.g. opencv). But you can write additional functions to detect the QR codes and to test whether the detected checker board corners are at the right place (and not rotated by 180°) by comparing them with the QR code positions. And, if QR codes are detected, you can know whether there should be a pattern detected in the image. It's more like some helpers to make it more robust and more practically usable.

Comment: I see no need for all that, as long as you use patterns that have no symmetry. both pictures you showed are good. -- the only "fancy" board I would recommend is the "charuco" variant, because that doesn't need to be fully in view to give you usable points.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz dont 180° rotations/detections make a difference for stereo calibration?

Comment: they do, but those boards don't have that rotational symmetry. they may be mirrored but that doesn't happen, and viewing them from the back doesn't either. -- those boards have a particular number of rows and columns. one is even, the other is odd.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz i try to use the ChAruCo board. You recommended me this bread, 
on the [calib.io](https://calib.io/blogs/knowledge-base/calibration-patterns-explained) web page recommended ChAruCo to, if you use OpenCV > 3.x. Im using OpenCV 4.6.0.66 but i can not find the aruco modul. What's worng?
[Image](https://s20.directupload.net/images/220617/gy9bnm5e.png)

Comment: does the code run though? squiggles in an editor mean nothing.

Comment: I may not understand exactly what the word "180-degree ambiguity" means ...
In the top-left black square of my favorite chessboard pattern has a white filled circle.
In my experience, this mark does not interfere with pattern detection. And detecting this circular mark is very easy additional work.

Comment: @fana basicaly 180-degree ambiguity means, the pattern should not look the same when rotated by 180 degrees :). 
Look the examples of patterns that contain 180-degree ambiguity, and should not be avoided when calibraiting stereo cameras:
[Single camera calibration](https://s20.directupload.net/images/220621/fz4qh7oo.png)
For stereo calibratin use a checkerboard that contains an even number of squares along one edge and an odd number of squares along the other edge.
[[Stereo camera calibration](https://s20.directupload.net/images/220621/ej7x4or4.png)

Comment: @I2I3 Thanks. My understanding (:what needed is defining which feature point is origin) seems to be correct.
But I don't think this is so important.
Because I believe that, for calibration work, all pattern detection result should be checked carefully by our eye.
If we find invalid detection result, we must remove or correct it.
At such confirming work, we know relational pose between 2 cameras roughly, so this 180-degree problem can be simply found by our eye and easily corrected.

Comment: @l2l3 The aruco module is part of opencv-contrib-python, you likely have opencv-python

Comment: @code-lukas correct, and i have the right modul "opencv-contrib-python".
You should to write ´from c2 import aruco´ not ´from cv2.aruco import aruco´ if you don't want squiggles in an editor. 
ChristophRackwitz is right. That means noting. See up in the comment from Jun.17 at 18:31 the image. 
Actually im working on the stereo calibration with the charuco pattern. I find the calibration with charuco very well.